# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jdbc, sql-server-2008-r2

**caused by connection reset**

I am trying to connect my java program to sql server 20008 r2 through hibernate but i am getting [image: this] error

**main class is as follows**

```
package com.prizm;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;
public class SecondPractice {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Configuration configuration = new
            Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        ServiceRegistryBuilder registry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
        registry.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = registry.buildServiceRegistry();
        SessionFactorysessionFactory=configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Student lecturer = new Student();
        lecturer.setFirstname("raj");
        lecturer.setLastname("kumar");
        session.save(lecturer);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

So where i am making mistake, what do i need to know about this error, how to solve it
Thanks in advance

Here i have edited my question and posted the different code from the aforementioned as i am not comfortable with log4J properties so i have tried to connect my java code to database through **JDBC** , connection is getting done but when it comes about creating any table or any thing else related to data transfer it gives me the same error as i have mentioned.

**Here is the code for JDBC along with Logger api of java (java.util.Logger)**

```
package com.prizm;
import java.sql.*; 
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;
public class JKL {
public static Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(JKL.class.getName());
public static FileHandler fh=null;
public static void init(){
try{
fh=new FileHandler("logger.log",false);
}catch(Exception e){}
fh.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
Logger l=Logger.getLogger("");
l.addHandler(fh);
Connection con=null;
try{
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver());
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://167.01.09.12;IntegratedSecurity=true");
if(con!=null){
    System.out.println("done");
}
Statement st=con.createStatement();
st.executeUpdate("create table hi(id int,name varchar(50))");
}catch(SQLException e){l.log(Level.SEVERE,"Here is your error",e);}
}
public static void main(String args[]){
JKL.init();
}
}
```

**and the log record that i am getting is this**

[image: this]]

so what should i understand from it, do i need to do something with the configuration of microsoft sql server 2008 r2 , as i have sp1 version and this piece of code is working very fine on my friend's computer.

Comment: Configure log4j.properties so that you can get debug logs. post that we can diagnose

Comment: i have class SecondPractice.class so how to configure the log4j.properties into my file, i have log4j.jar file into my library, i don't have much knowledge about log4j.jar can you post the codes for that.

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace as **text**, not as screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java 6u29 there was a bug introduced by oracle with bug id : 7103725 which restricts the **SSL Connections** to SQL Server 2008 and except java version 1.6.0_24 it will give the aforementioned error, to solve this problem we have to pass following property and value to java

*-Djsse.enableCBCProtection=false*

and as i am using eclipse the steps are as follows

RunAs>>RunConfiguration>>VMArgument and inside the block,copy this property and value, for more detail follow this [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fishkb/java-sql-sqlexception-i-o-error-connection-reset-when-connecting-to-an-external-sql-server-2008-database-284365810.html).